# How to display irregularly-repeated yet identical images so that their borders align between rows?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I'm trying to recreate a "pixelated" version of the [Space Invaders icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhWOY.png) in HTML/CSS using individual `30px` [square images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id6co.jpg) with a **blue** border of `2px` between the squares.

However, I'm having *incredible* difficulty aligning the `2px` borders since the square image is **not** repeated *equally* on each row (e.g. the first 2 rows only display the square image twice, while the 3rd row displays it 7 times, etc.).

I first imagined an 11 x 8 rectangular grid, and then I used a `<div>` with the same width and height as the square images and with *no border* as **placeholders** where the images are not meant to appear, while displaying each square image with a solid border of `1px` where they are meant to appear.

The problem with that is that while the images on the inside correctly display a doubled-up border of `2px` (`1px` + `1px` borders), the outermost squares only display a `1px` border on the outside sides that are not next to another square.

So then I tried setting `2px` borders on the "outer sides" of the "outer squares", but that then changed the entire "line height" of the row of images (using `vertical-align: middle;`) in that entire row from `1px` to `2px`, creating an empty white space `1px` high at the top of the inner squares.

So I've been pulling my hair for the last several hours trying to get this to look "right" with the `2px` borders properly aligned in a "grid" while not appearing where no square image is meant to show, but I'm going in circles.

Surely, there is a simpler, more straightforward way of doing this.  **What's the magic solution?**

Comment: Can you show us your HTML/CSS? I would recommend using squares for each "pixel" (whether it's black or green) and always having a 2px border.  On the black squares, you just set the border to black so it doesn't really appear as anything.

Comment: i've done some 8bit css graphics too...there's a pretty standard formula i use, post your code and i'll point out how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

So, since you have been pulling your hair on the problem, I guessed I might suggest a simpler solution to it, perhaps not exactly an answer to your question, which is very difficult to give without an HTML example.

I made this CSS-only space invader:

<kbd>[**CSS-only Space Invader!**](http://jsbin.com/eranoc/1)</kbd>

Basically what you do is have a general CSS rule for your pixels `<div>`s, I have it defined like so:

```
div{ 
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Of course, please, choose something less general than `div`, I did it just for the example purpose. In this way you have a div making up your transparent pixels. Everytime you need to fill up a pixel in your image, just add a class (I used `.px`) with this minimal CSS rule

```
.px{ 
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

When you are starting your new line, give your `div` a class of `.first` and make it `clear:left`.

```
.first{ 
  clear:left;
}
```

I think this is a pretty simple solution! **Bring on the CSS pixel art!**

Comment: Very clever!  However, I need to use actual images as the background, and I need to make them clickable (links) to different pages.  How would I do that with your clever CSS solution?

Comment: To be clear: I need to use **different** images as the actual visible squares (and make them clickable).

Comment: What would the problem be? Change the element holding the filled pixels with `<a href="yourlink">` instead of `<div>`. Set different classes with different `background-image` instead of `background-color` and then fill them in as you please. [**See this example**](http://jsbin.com/eranoc/5)

Comment: The problem is I need to set the images dynamically in the HTML body, not CSS, so I can't set different classes with different `background-image`.  Should I use `style="background-images:...` to set them in HTML, or do you recommend a better way?  Please let me know and thanks again!

Comment: Using `style='background-image'` is totally an option if you want to use this solution. To propose other solutions you should elaborate a bit more on your usage case; perhaps with a fiddle? How are they going to be se dynamically? Javascript? PHP?